# Check at runtime whether installer has Uninstallable=True?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript, delphi

I have this little piece of code that occurs at post-install step:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin

  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then begin
    CreateSymbolicLink(ExpandConstant('{app}\Uninstall.vsf'), ExpandConstant('{cf}\Inno Setup\Carbon.vsf'), 0)
    CreateSymbolicLink(ExpandConstant('{app}\Uninstall.dll'), ExpandConstant('{cf}\Inno Setup\VclStylesinno.dll'), 0)
  end;

end;
```

I would like to accomodate it to create the symbolic links only if the installer has the `Uninstallable=True`, how I could chek that from pascal script?.

Note that I also pretend to determine it in scenarios like this: `Uninstallable=not IsTaskSelected('task name')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `#define` to store the value. You can check the value of it in the code section using `ExpandConstant`.

Example:

```
#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define Uninstallable "no"

[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
Uninstallable={#Uninstallable}

[Code]  
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin    
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then begin
    if LowerCase(ExpandConstant('{#Uninstallable}')) = 'yes' then
    begin
      CreateSymbolicLink(ExpandConstant('{app}\Uninstall.vsf'), ExpandConstant('{cf}\Inno Setup\Carbon.vsf'), 0);
      CreateSymbolicLink(ExpandConstant('{app}\Uninstall.dll'), ExpandConstant('{cf}\Inno Setup\VclStylesinno.dll'), 0);
    end;
  end;    
end;
```

Comment: Thankyou, but then what happens if I have `Uninstallable=not IsTaskSelected('task name')` ? in that case I imagine can't store the value in a constant at top of the script.

Comment: How do you set `Uninstallable` on runtime? If it is set to `yes` an uninstaller will be created on compile time. So it makes no sense to me trying to set the value programmatically. Maybe I'm just getting you wrong.

Comment: See what I mean: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_uninstallable.htm, uninstaller is included, but it can be selectively expanded to disk or not depending on the task that the user switches.

Comment: You can call IsTaskSelected programmatically. Doesn't it work if you do so?